# A new partition appeared in nautilus

Tags: mount, 20.04

I don't know how this new mounted partition named, "52 MB Volume" appeared.

[image: 52 MB volume]

It can be ejected with the message

> 52MB Volume unmounted filesystem has been disconnected
>   Is it something to worry about?

Output of `mount`:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=4005860k,nr_inodes=1001465,mode=755)
    devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
    tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=806800k,mode=755)
    /dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
    securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
    tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
    tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
    cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
    pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
    systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=16468)
    debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
    mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_95.snap on /snap/canonical-livepatch/95 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_110.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_116.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_9066.snap on /snap/core/9066 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1754.snap on /snap/core18/1754 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_9289.snap on /snap/core/9289 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1705.snap on /snap/core18/1705 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_145.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_33.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/rambox_13.snap on /snap/rambox/13 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1502.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_128.snap on /snap/skype/128 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_41.snap on /snap/spotify/41 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_148.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1506.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_123.snap on /snap/skype/123 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_36.snap on /snap/spotify/36 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1397.snap on /snap/vlc/1397 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1620.snap on /snap/vlc/1620 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_36.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
    /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
    binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=806800k,mode=755)
    nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/canonical-livepatch.mnt type nsfs (rw)
    tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=806796k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
    gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
    /dev/fuse on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
    nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/rambox.mnt type nsfs (rw)
    nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/vlc.mnt type nsfs (rw)
    nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/spotify.mnt type nsfs (rw)
```

The output of `df`-

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4005860         0   4005860   0% /dev
tmpfs             806800      1932    804868   1% /run
/dev/sda2      959863856 338194016 572841632  38% /
tmpfs            4033988    181296   3852692   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4033988         0   4033988   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0          9344      9344         0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop3        164096    164096         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop4         96256     96256         0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop1         56320     56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop6         99456     99456         0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop2         56320     56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop5        165376    165376         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop7        261760    261760         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/loop10         2304      2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
/dev/loop9          2304      2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop12        63616     63616         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop14        64512     64512         0 100% /snap/rambox/13
/dev/loop8        261760    261760         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop13       176128    176128         0 100% /snap/skype/123
/dev/loop11        56192     56192         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop15       178432    178432         0 100% /snap/skype/128
/dev/loop16       167680    167680         0 100% /snap/spotify/41
/dev/loop19       207872    207872         0 100% /snap/vlc/1397
/dev/loop17       185472    185472         0 100% /snap/spotify/36
/dev/loop18       297984    297984         0 100% /snap/vlc/1620
/dev/sda1         523248      7944    515304   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             806796        56    806740   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: That might be a partition that is left there as the result of creating or shrinking the partitions. Look at the partitions on your system via [GParted](https://linuxhint.com/gparted_ubuntu/)

Comment: I can't find any such partition via Gparted

Comment: Have you mounted an ISO file for example or some other file-based filesystems ?

Comment: What about `df`?

Comment: @Prachi I guess it is the recovery tool partition, which requires a minimum of 52mb

Comment: I noticed the same today, 52 mb volume. So I did a restart and discovered it was a firmware update.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Snap partition. You can hide it using `gnome-disks` without any issues, but please do not unmount it.

Comment: Why was this randomly added, though? It was never there before. I've also never seen it in the Disks app until now, either.

Comment: @dspacejs Did you upgrade your system from an older version of Ubuntu to Ubuntu 20.04/20.10? This may be the reason.